# Gurobi Jupyter Notebook solution not showing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-programming, gurobi

I typed the following code in my jupyter notebook but its not giving me any optimal solution. It's just giving me this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxaZI.png). Could someone help me out?

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

try:

    # Create a new model
    m = gp.Model("Diet")

    # Create variables
    x = m.addVar(vtype="C", name="x")
    y = m.addVar(vtype="C", name="y")
    z = m.addVar(vtype="C", name="z")
    a = m.addVar(vtype="C", name="a")

    # Set objective
    m.setObjective(50*x + 20*y + 30*z + 80*a, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

    # Add constraint:
    m.addConstr(400 * x + 200 * y + 150 * z + 500 * a >= 500, "c0")

    # Add constraint: 
    m.addConstr(3 * x + 2 * y >= 6, "c1")
    
    # Add constraint: 
    m.addConstr(2 * x + 2 * y + 4 * z + 4 * a >= 10, "c2")
    
    # Add constraint: 
    m.addConstr(2 * x + 4 * y + z + 5 * a >= 8, "c3")
    

    # Optimize model
    m.optimize()

    for v in m.getVars():
        print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))

    print('Obj: %g' % m.objVal)

except gp.GurobiError as e:
    print('Error code ' + str(e.errno) + ': ' + str(e))

except AttributeError:
    print('Encountered an attribute error')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution isn't printing because it didn't find an optimal solution.  `Infeasible or unbounded model` means that either it's infeasible i.e. no solution exists, or it's unbounded i.e. it can continue increasing/decreasing the values of the variables without limit to improve the objective without limit.

Looking at the model, it does indeed appear to be unbounded. You have as the objective

```
m.setObjective(50*x + 20*y + 30*z + 80*a, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

and there is no upper limit on any of these variables.  If you change this to

```
m.setObjective(50*x + 20*y + 30*z + 80*a, GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

then you should get the optimal solution for *minimizing* this objective.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked after I changed it to minimize.